# Aryanization in Nazi Germany. What did it mean in reality?

Tags: nazi-germany

[Arthur Eichengrün](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Eichengr%C3%BCn) was a Jewish chemist who lived in Germany and was running his own chemical company. In 1938 his company has been "aryanized". But as late as 1943 he got arrested for failing to indicate the Jewishness in  his company's name. He spent 4 months in prison, but got arrested again a year later on the same charge and spent 14 months in a camp.

How this can be true? Had he retain any influence in his company after it was "aryanized" and if it was why the Nazis demanded him to indicate the Jewishness of the owner in the company's name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Wikipedia article to which you give the link is a bit vague. There is a better account of him here:
http://www.encyclopedia.com/doc/1G2-2830905643.html

especially this:

“The Cellon-Werke prospered, but in 1933 Eichengrün had to sell part of his share in the company to Germans of Aryan descent. In 1938 the Nazis forced him to withdraw completely from his company, and as a result he sold his firm to the Chemische Fabrik Dr. Joachim Wiernik & Co. in Berlin-Waidmannslust. Due to his reputation and influential contacts, Eichengrün remained free and continued his research at home until he was imprisoned for four months in 1943 for failing to include the statutory “Israel” as part of his name in a letter to a Reich official. In May 1944, he was deported to Theriesenstadt concentration camp until its liberation by the Red Army. He returned to Berlin after the war to continue his scientific work in private.”

Comment: So it was not about the company's name as the Wikipedia claims?

Comment: So it seems. The linked article is taken from the "Dictionary of Scientific biography" which is a reputable reference work, unlike Wikipedia.